# VS Code Extension "Cannot find module 'supports-color'" error

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I followed the steps [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to start building an extension for VS Code. I didn't change any code, pressed F5 and I got this error.

I have searched and I cannot find anything that can help me solve this error.

I have deleted the package-lock.json file, and node-modules folder, cleared the cache, and ran npm install.

```
Exception has occurred: Error: Cannot find module 'supports-color'
Require stack:
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/node_modules/debug/src/index.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/dist/index.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-proxy-agent/out/agent.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-proxy-agent/out/index.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork.js
  at Function._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:934:15)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:27
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:28:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/node_modules/debug/src/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/get-uri/dist/index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-proxy-agent/out/agent.js:17:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-proxy-agent/out/index.js:40:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at t (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:101)
    at r.load (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:1719)
    at r.load (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10262)
    at l (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10314)
    at r._loadModule (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10444)
    at r._resolve (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:6:452)
    at r.defineModule (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:6145)
    at p (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:6:1702)
    at _ (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:2553)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:96:56534)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:106:31882)
    at r._createAndEvalScript (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:2597)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:2236
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
    at FSReqCallback.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14)
```

Comment: Found solution? @mrgnhnt96

Comment: I have not unfortunately